# arcpy SearchCursor return a OBJECTID value not as an integer

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, vb.net, statistics, search

I use summary statistics GP tool to extract the max OBJECTID from a feature layer. After that I use arcpy SerachCursor to get the OBJECTID value from the statistics, but the result returned is not an integer.

The statistics contents:

[image]

The result of SearchCursor:

[image]

The python code:

```
import arcpy

arcpy.env.workspace = "C:/Users/lyao/Documents/ArcGIS/Default.gdb"
feature = "C:/Users/lyao/Documents/ArcGIS/Default.gdb/BQ_Segment_1_Statistics1"

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(feature, ("MAX_geri_db_DBO_BQ_Segment_1_OBJECTID",), '"OBJECTID" = 1') as cursor:
for row in cursor:
    print str(row[0])
```

I want to know:

1. How to get the exact same OBJECTID as in the statistics.
2. I am using vb.net, so I want to know how to return the result to vb.net.

I am using arcmap 10.2.

Comment: It should be an integer, you're making it a string to print it. How would you return that to vb? Wouldn't you skip the python and read the table as ITable in vb.net?

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for the quick reply. In fact my application is developed in vb.net, I have no idea what to do in vb.net that is the same as search cursor in arcpy.

Comment: do you have the Esri SDK installed?

Comment: yes I have arcObjects sdk installed.

Comment: There's a lot more to it, but I'll put something together as a sample. Will this be an add-in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In VB.net:

```
Dim pWSF As ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IWorkspaceFactory = New ESRI.ArcGIS.DataSourcesGDB.FileGDBWorkspaceFactory()
Dim pWS As ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IWorkspace = pWSF.OpenFromFile("C:/Users/lyao/Documents/ArcGIS/Default.gdb", 0)
Dim pFws As ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IFeatureWorkspace = CType(pWS, ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IFeatureWorkspace)
Dim pTable As ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.ITable = pFws.OpenTable("BQ_Segment_1_Statistics1")
Dim pCur As ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.ICursor = pTable.Search(Nothing, False) ' open the cursor
Dim pRow As ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IRow = pCur.NextRow ' first row
Dim pValue As Integer = pRow.Value(2)   ' the value in the 3rd column
```

That is assuming that the table never deviates from the format shown.

You start with an IWorkspaceFactory (set the type to match the database) from which you create an IWorkspace which gets changed into a IFeatureWorkspace which is able to open the table. With the table start the cursor, get the first row and then retrieve the value.

You can see why arcpy is so popular... The online help will give some explanation and options for the objects shown but that's the way to open a table from scratch.

Comment: Hi Michael, is there a way of mapping values of different fields in an attribute table? I will open a new question for it.

Comment: I think it would be best posted as another question. I would need more information on what you're trying to achieve to provide the correct guidance.

Comment: Hi Michael, the new question is http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/114251/vb-net-arcobjects-mapping-different-field-values-in-attribute-table, please check whether the information is enough.