# vb.net arcobjects mapping different field values in attribute table

Tags: attribute-table, vb.net, field-mapping

I need to mapping different field values in an attribute table. The attribute table as follows:

[image]

For example, I want to get the "DrainName" value when "BQ no." = "22/22" and "Segment ID" = "22/22-1". The result should return 2 values.

Is there a way vb.net to do this? Thanks.

Comment: Are you just trying to 'select' those two values?

Comment: Hi Michael, select these two values is my current design. Later I may also need to mapping the whole table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following on from the previous [arcpy SearchCursor return a OBJECTID value not as an integer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/114247/arcpy-searchcursor-return-a-objectid-value-not-as-an-integer)

```
Dim pQF As ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IQueryFilter = New ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.QueryFilter()
pQF.WhereClause = "BQ no. = '22/22' and Segment ID = '22/22-1'" 'exactly the same as Select by Attributes'
Dim pCur As ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.ICursor = pTable.Search(pQF, False) ' open the cursor'
Dim pFieldIndex As Integer = pTable.Fields.FindField("DrainName") ' get the index of the field "DrainName" or -1 if it's not found
Dim pRow As ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IRow = pCur.NextRow ' first row'
Do Until pRow Is Nothing
    Debug.Print(pRow.Value(pFieldIndex)) ' do something important here'
    pRow = pCur.NextRow
Loop
```

To limit the returned rows use IQueryFilter interface (or ISpatialFilter - another handy one if you want to select by location).

In VB you get the value by its index not the field name; to get the index use ITable.Fields.FindField (IFeatureClass.Fields.FindField is the same) to get the index.

I have a feeling that you have field aliases and not field names, that might cause problems with the whereclause of the query - use the field names instead for better results.

Comment: Hi Michael you are so nice, thank you very much for the help. I will follow your instruction. Yes I have field aliases, will pay attention when use it in the query.

Comment: It might work, I don't know. I don't use field aliases. I would do *Select by attributes* in ArcMap on the table and if I like the results then copy the query from the window and put quote marks around it for the where clause - that always works for me.

Comment: Thanks Michael. any hints of mapping the whole table? I feel there should have a GP to mapping fields for the whole table, but so sad I haven't found it.

Comment: to do the whole table go back to pTable.Search(Nothing,False) - Nothing means everything, it's a bit counter-intuitive but works.

Comment: Hi Michael, I use the code you provide to read data from a dbf file. I find if I do some simple thing in the loop, the map just crash once all values retrieved correctly. I open a new question as follows: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/114937/vb-net-arcmap-add-in-loop-through-a-dbf-file-get-system-nullreferenceexception , if possible, can please have a look? many thanks.

Comment: Hi Michael, I have got the answer for the above-mentioned question. Still need to thank you for the help in many of my questions.